# Problems with creating an azure function in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

So I right click on the solution > add > new project > find azure function > choose template > create that

And then nothing happens. If I swap to folder view, I see a new folder made for the function, but its an empty folder.

Weirdest thing is, this was working perfectly fine and a moment later, it became how it is right now. I've not updated vs in between, I've not restarted in between. It was literally closed vs, opened again, and then vs broke.

Older solutions that has functions in them, tried creating a new one, doesn't work same story. Made new solutions and start it off with creating a function, didn't work as well. Reinstalled vs, also did not help, still the same issue. Any ideas how I broke vs?

Also, this works from powershell, I can create functions from there and then go back to vs to add an existing project. However the functions I've build using this method had runtime errors (I think) when I publish them into azure. Regardless, I really would like to be able to create functions normally in vs.

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour (with recently downloaded VS 2022). It creates a solution without any project files (class, setting, etc). It does not matter what type of function I create. It does nothing. And there are no errors. Weird. But when I try a recently downloaded VS 2019, it seems to work fine. VS 2019 creates the function class and everything.

Comment: I reported this problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-is-failing-to-create-an-azure-function-proj-2/1680557

Comment: Same thing happening to me.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. Go into Tools > Get Tools and Features > download the .NET desktop development.

I have never installed this on my initial install of vs, I have no clue why closing and reopening vs made me need to have this. But nonetheless, I can create functions now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from the comment section of the question, the solution was:

- Go into **Tools** -> **Get Tools and Features**
- download the .Net desktop development

As Maybemonday described in his/her comment, functions can be created afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issues by installing the right tools.

When setting up the VS 2022 -OR- by navigating to Tools -> Get Tools and Features, install the following workloads:

1. .Net Desktop Development
2. Azure development

You can also observe the icon changes from a "Project" type to "Azure Function App" type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but once I renamed C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet to C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet.delete, it started working. I think the x86 dotnet binary was earlier in the path and was causing issues.